# pgfplot axis xlabel right justified at east end of axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw an x axis with the axis label not centered,
but on the right side of the axis. Something like `anchor=east and pos=east`
for the `xlabel`.
Is this possible?

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xlabel=$p_{T} (GeV/c)$, ylabel=abundance, ymode=log]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an answer to your follow-up comment posted after @Peter's answer: you asked how to keep the vertical position while moving only the horizontal one.

Here is how to proceed:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$p_{T} (GeV/c)$, ylabel=abundance, ymode=log,
    xlabel style={
        at={(ticklabel cs:1)},
        anchor=north west,
    },%
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Attention: I also added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}`. It is generally best-practise to write a compat level of at least `1.3`. If you have a document which is more than 4 years old and you want to keep its label positions (i.e. you do not want to write the `compat` key), I can post a slightly different answer.

The  default axis placement (as of version 1.3) is `at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel`. The `0.5` means to place it in the middle of the (respective) axis. In your case, I said `1` to indicate that it should use the upper end, and I wrote an anchor as requested. The `ticklabel cs` takes care of the size of tick labels.

Comment: Perfect, that's excactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can include a style for the `xlabel`:

```
xlabel style={
        at={(current axis.right of origin)}, 
        xshift=7.5ex, anchor=center
    }
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xlabel=$p_{T} (GeV/c)$, ylabel=abundance, ymode=log,
xlabel style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)}, 
            xshift=7.5ex, anchor=center
        }]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's getting closer. Modifying your example I get what I want.
But I would have liked to keep the vertical position unchanged instead
of forcing it with the yshift.  
  
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$p_{T} (GeV/c)$, ylabel=abundance, ymode=log,   
xlabel style={    
            at={(current axis.right of origin)},   
            yshift=-4.5ex, anchor=east    
        }]   
\end{axis}